# How / Is it possible to have a vector<unique_ptr<ABC>>?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr, abstract-base-class

Revamping some old code where I was manually handling lifetimes of a vector of raw pointers to concrete instances of an abstract base class (ABC).

So the vector's owner had a virtual dtor which manually went through and deleted the contents of the vector, etc.

Since the vector's owner owns the elements in it, it makes a lot of sense to change this to a vector of unique_ptr's.

Sadly, it seems this is impossible? Because a `vector<unique_ptr<type>>` must be able to have a static dtor for `type` but because in this case type is an ABC, that is not available, hence the `vector` won't compile...

Or am I missing something?

e.g.:

```
struct ABC
{
    ABC() = default;
    virtual ~ABC() { } // need a vtable entry so that concrete subclasses will be deleted through the base dtor

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ABC> Clone() = 0;
    virtual void Foo() = 0;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ABC>>   elements;
};
```

EDIT2: here's a complete example that fails:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct ABC
{
    virtual ~ABC() { } // need a vtable entry so that concrete subclasses will be deleted through the base dtor

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ABC> Clone() = 0;
    virtual void Foo() = 0;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ABC>>   elements;
};

struct Child : ABC
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> Clone() override { return std::make_unique<Child>(*this); }
    void Foo() override { };
};

struct Derived : Child
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> Clone() override { return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> x;
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> c = std::make_unique<Child>();

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ABC>>   elements;
    elements.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Derived>());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about everyone else but if you use the same names from the example code in the question it makes what you are asking a lot clearer.  That said, what is the error you get?  Your example code compile for me.

Comment: Couldn't you just forward declare Base? Right before you define it?

Comment: I get a mile long set of messages from VS 2015 Upd 3 which basically is a failure to instantiate the default fill `elements` for the vector due to a delete ctor in Base (presumably because it is an ABC)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, exactly.  I have no issue with that - that is what I want!  If the compiler would agree to do so... ;)

Comment: The error message states that you are preforming a copy of a `unique_ptr<Base>` somewhere. It's complaining that you are referring to a function that is deleted, which the copy constructor if `unique_ptr` is. It's not complaining about a "delete function".

Comment: Weird.  When I run [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16ab964f5c94e18a) I have no problems with it on my version of MSVS 2015.  I am also on upate 3.  Please provide a [mcve] that gives those errors.

Comment: Thanks - I'm looking further into it now.  I'll post when I have such a thing...

Comment: Updated based on feedback - and found in deriving a verifiable example that it is the last line of ABC `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ABC>>   elements;` that causes the compiler errors.  If I omit this, I have no errors...?

Comment: Ah,I see, it's the `Clone()` functions - they're explicitly attempting to copy the elements in the base.  d'oh!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs when you try to copy an instance of `Base` or an instance of a type derived from `Base`. The default copy constructor will attempt to copy `Base::elements`, which attempts to copy each of it's elements into the new `vector`. Since these elements are `unique_ptr<Base>` this copy is not allowed.

This example reproduces the problem :

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Base
{
    using PBase = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
    using VBase = std::vector<PBase>;

    VBase   elements;
};

int main()
{
    Base x;
    auto y = x; // This line causes the error

    return 0;
}
```

You will likely need to implement your own copy constructor and copy assignment operator, or forbid copying by deleting these functions. Using `shared_ptr` instead might work, if shallow copies will work for your application.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wasn't seeing the obvious.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, here's what I should have been doing:

```
class ABC
{
public:
    ABC() = default;
    ABC(const ABC & rhs)
    {
        // manually clone our elements
        elements.reserve(rhs.elements.size());
        for (const auto & e : rhs.elements)
            elements.emplace_back(e->Clone());
    }
    ABC & operator = (const ABC &) = delete;

    virtual ~ABC() { } // need a vtable entry so that concrete subclasses will be deleted through the base dtor

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ABC> Clone() = 0;
    virtual void Foo() = 0;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ABC>>   elements;
};
```